# Ryanair cabin baggage & MacBook 15"

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, ryanair, low-cost-carriers

According to [Ryanair policy](https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/Baggage/What-cabin-baggage-can-I-carry):

> **What you CAN bring on board**
>
> All passengers are entitled to bring 1 small personal bag on board which must fit under the seat in front of you (35cm x 20cm x 20cm). Examples include, handbag, laptop bag, and a small back pack.

I'm afraid for my MacBook's safety, so I want it to be with me.

Can I bring it to a cabin? Maybe someone has own experience.

MacBook Pro 15" size is `35x24x1`, and `38x27x2.5` with its bag and I don't want to place it under the seat...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to place it under the seat? That's where I prefer to have my laptop when flying. It's convenient and safe, and small enough so I still have room for my feet. I have a MacBook 15" as well, and although I've (thankfully) never flown Ryanair, I've never had a problem putting it under the seat on other airlines.

Comment: Where do you ideally want your laptop to go? No airline will let you keep it on your lap, and you don't want it under these seat. I'm not sure I understand what you want to do with your laptop during the flight.

Comment: @skifans put it in the overhead locker? In the majority of cases, that’s where my 15” MacBook Pro goes. But it’s been a while since I last flew with Ryanair...

Comment: I think the point is that the MacBook (like other 15" laptops) exceeds the maximum size of the 'small personal bag', and Ryanair now charge extra if you want to bring a larger bag than this on board. I assume the question is whether Ryanair strictly enforce this size limit when the bag is a laptop bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have flown Ryanair at least 10 times under the new hand luggage policy and I never had a problem bringing my laptop on-board in a slightly over-sized "small bag" (while gate-checking a suitcase as carry-on).

At some airports even the manual bag tags advise you to take out your valuables and lithium batteries: 
[image]

Regarding where to put your laptop/bag on the plane, I don't see a problem with placing it under the seat in front of you. If you place it in the overhead lockers and the plane is packed with suitcases, the flight attendants might ask you to take it out again.

Be aware the main priority for Ryanair staff is to turn around the plane as quickly as possible. So if you are not obviously breaking rules and are not in the way of their procedures, they typically don't care.

Comment: Yes, I was a little surprised that a large number of passengers took huge bags with them without worrying about it, and I was worried about a small laptop.